# How to fix clang include path warning in Eclipse CDT for Hello World project (mac OS)

Tags: eclipse, include, warnings, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 CDT 8.5.0 in mac OS X Yosemite.

When creating any C++ project (Hello world one for example), even if it compiles and runs correctly, there is always a warning for the include path: 
(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/6.0/include).

That path doesn't exist.

Why is the include path automatically generated and how can I change the include path to a correct one?

Is that include really needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing path may be the result of applying updates to xcode.  The new clang version is 6.1, and the 6.0 path no longer exists.

I found the fix only by poking around the settings.  Hopefully this will work for you:

Go to workspace settings (`cmd ,`)

Then `C/C++ --> Build --> Settings` and click on the `Discovery` button.

Then click on `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` to highlight it.

Click on the `Reset` button to the right.

The include paths should be updated.

Comment: This worked. You have to check the "Allocate console in the Console view" flag to be able to reset it too. For some projects I've also needed to refresh the C/C++ General -> Preprocessor include paths -> GNU GCC -> CDT GCC Built-in compiler settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to a new Xcode version such as v7.0.0, OS X asks for agreeing to a license agreement by prompting:

> "Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please
>   re-run as root via sudo."

You can open up a terminal and type in "sudo gcc" and enter your admin password to accept the license agreement. Only after this is done, eclipse Discover can generate the updated include paths for CDT GCC Built-in Settings.